# How do I find when a UITabBar switches UITabItem's in iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I need this so when I switch tab items it moves an array item in to another array.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using a `UITabBarController` you'll want the `UITabBarController` delegate method `tabBarController:didSelectViewController:`.